# black screen after logout

Tags: unity, 13.04, gnome, login, mate

I have ubuntu 13.04 installed and normally I use MATE as desktop viewer. After I logout and login with the default desktop viewer (Unity? gnome?) the screen is black and just the ubuntu logo appears.
I can work via console (control+alt+f1), how can I restart all with MATE?

Comment: Does `sudo restart lightdm` work?

Comment: I did so, and the terminal says "restart: unknown instance...

Comment: Then try `service lightdm restart`, `sudo stop lightdm && sudo start lightdm` and if this doesn't work then install lightdm.

Comment: I tried ´sudo restart gdm´and then I rebooted. It seems working now! So I guess it was a gnome problem..

Comment: OK. Should I post my comment as an answer now?

Comment: Yeah, even if it wasn't the perfect command, it has enlighten me.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, Ubuntu uses [lightdm](https://launchpad.net/lightdm) as session manager. But the older versions of Ubuntu used [GDM](https://launchpad.net/gdm). Once you logged in to the terminal, you can use these commands to re-enable graphical login:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

or, if that fails

```
sudo restart gdm
```